# Dropbox API Token flow - no token in response

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, dropbox-api

I'm trying to work with the Dropbox API in my current C# application.
At the moment I'm struggling with the OAuth2 authentication (implicit flow).

First of all I chose the implicit flow because I develop a pure client-side app and regarding to the API's documentation this flow is made for this type of application.
Next I prepared the request:

```
https://www.dropbox.com/1/oauth2/authorize?response_type=token&client_id=MYCLIENTID&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost
```

Then I setup a simple `TcpListener` listening on port 80 to receive the callback from Dropbox. For testing purposes I just accept a `TcpClient` and create a `StreamReader` reading the accepted client's stream line per line.

```
var listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 80);
listener.Start();

var client = listener.AcceptTcpClient();

using (var reader = new StreamReader(client.GetStream()))
{
    string line = null;
    while((line = reader.ReadLine()) != "") { }
}
```

For the consent dialog I just create a `Window` with a `WebBrowser` control in it at the moment:

```
var browser = new WebBrowser {Source = new Uri(authUri)};
var window = new Window {Content = browser};
```

... where `authUri` is the request uri from above.

Now the documentation says that a sample response for this flow could be:

```
[REDIRECT_URI]#access_token=ABCDEFG&token_type=bearer&uid=12345&state=[STATE]
```

So when starting the application it shows me the consent dialog. I enter my credentials and click on "Allow". Then my `listener` kicks in and accepts a new client. In the debugger I now step into the `using` block and read the stream line per line to check what was returned.
I expect something like `GET /#access_token....` as the content of the first line but I actually get `GET / HTTP1.1`. The following lines only contain some headers without any important information.

After that I tried the `code` flow if this actually works. No problems at all. I get the authentication code and call `/token` with the necessary parameters and get the desired authentication token. The only problem with this flow is that I have to provide my app secret and from what I know about the app secret is that it should never be in a client app not running on your own servers to prevent it being compromised.

I really can't figure out why I can't get the token in the implicit flow so maybe anyone of you can help me out on this. I'm intentionally not using any third-party libraries in order to improve my own skills. Please don't mind that I'm not doing any error checking in the code samples as it is only for testing purposes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the implicit flow, the access token is part of the fragment of the URL (the part after the hash). URL fragments aren't sent to the server.

BTW, you might take a look at https://blogs.dropbox.com/developers/2014/04/dropbox-authorization-in-a-windows-forms-app/. If you're embedding a `WebBrowser` control anyway, there's no need to redirect to `localhost` at all, which is a potential security win in addition to being a bit easier.

Comment: Works like a charm! :) I just had to listen to a different event than explained in the blog post because I'm using the System.Windows.Controls.WebBrowser control.